# django-rest-swagger nested serializers with readonly fields not rendered properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, documentation-generation

I'm building an API with django-rest-framework and I started using [django-rest-swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/) for documentation.
I have a nested serializer with some read_only fields, like this:

```
# this is the nested serializer
class Nested(serializers.Serializer):
    normal_field = serializers.CharField(help_text="normal")
    readonly_field = serializers.CharField(read_only=True,
                                           help_text="readonly")

# this is the parent one
class Parent(serializers.Serializer):
    nested_field = Nested()
```

In the generated docs, nested serializers in the **Parameters** part of the page are rendered with *field* data type and no hint is given about its content, they are just like other fields.

Now you can see the problem there, as I would like to inform the user that there is a readonly field that should not be sent as part of the nested data but I can not see a way of doing so.

The ideal would be having a model description in Data Type column, just like the **Response Class** [section](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html).

Is there any proper way of doing so?

Comment: django-rest-swagger  is no longer being maintained. use drf-yasg

Comment: the Question should be modified

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `drf_yasg` instead, Swagger will generate the documentation for APIs, but it's not absolutely right!
If you want to correct Swagger documentation, you can do it. You will need to use `swagger_auto_schema` decorator. Below is the sample code:

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

class ProductSuspendView(CreateAPIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        tags=['dashboard'],
        request_body=openapi.Schema(
            type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
            properties={
                'id': openapi.Schema(
                    type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER,
                    description='Id',
                ),
                'suspend_kinds': openapi.Schema(
                    type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY,
                    items=openapi.Items(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER),
                    description='Array suspend (Inappropriate image: 1, Insufficient information: 2,  Bad language: 3) (suspend_kinds=[1,2])'
                ),
            }
        ),
        responses={
            status.HTTP_200_OK: SuccessResponseSerializer,
            status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: ErrorResponseSerializer
        }
    )
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Suspend a product.
        """
        ...
        if success:
            return Response({'success': True}, status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response({'success': False}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ would be the right choice for this use case now. this is well maintained and support OpenAPI 3.0+. also it is now suggested by django-rest-framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** of everything please use [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) for documentation .

**2.** you can find its implementation in one of my repository [Kirpi](https://github.com/H4medRostami/Kirpi) and learn how to use that.

**3.** if you in **3.** ; have question,let me know.